# Backbone: Template not showing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I started yesterday with Backbone.js, and I don't know why the template is not showing, even though I can see that part being parsed.

This is my template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="area-template">
            <div id="area">
                <label for="alto">Alto</label>
                <input id="alto" name="alto" value=""/>

                <label for="ancho">Ancho</label>
                <input id="ancho" name="ancho" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div id="resultado" style="margin-top: 2em">
                El área de un rectángulo de alto <%-alto %> y ancho <%- ancho %> es <b><%- area %></b>
            </div>      
 </script>
```

And this is my Backbone code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                var Rectangulo = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: {
                    alto: 4,
                    ancho: 3
                },

                area: function() {
                    return this.get('alto') * this.get('ancho');
                },
                toTemplateJSON: function() {
                    var json = this.toJSON();
                    json.area = this.area();
                    return json;
                }
            });

            var Vista = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '#area',
                events: {
                    "change input[name='alto']": 'onChangeAlto',
                    "change input[name='ancho']": 'onChangeAncho'
                },
                template: _.template($('#area-template').html()),

                initialize: function() {
                    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'onChangeAlto', 'onChangeAncho');
                    this.model = new Rectangulo();  
                    this.model.on('change', this.render);

                    this.render();
                },

                onChangeAlto: function() {
                    var v = parseInt($("input[name='alto']", this.el).val());
                    this.model.set('alto', v);
                },

                onChangeAncho: function() {
                    var v = parseInt($("input[name='ancho']", this.el).val());
                    this.model.set('ancho', v);
                },

                render: function() {
                    $("input[name='alto']").val(this.model.get('alto'));
                    $("input[name='ancho']").val(this.model.get('ancho'));
                    this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.toTemplateJSON()));
                }
            });

            var v = new Vista();
   </script>
```

I'm not getting any errors, just a blank page. If I sabotage the template (for example by changing `<%- alto %>` to <`%- undefinedOne %>` I do get the error in the console (`ReferenceError: undefinedOne is not defined`). But why isn't the HTML being drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me, see : http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/14/

since you have defined the 'el' of your view is '#area'

you have to make sure, there's an element that has an id 'area' available in the DOM, or you will have to insert it manually:

```
var v = new Vista();
$('body').append(v.el);
```

================

**EDIT:**

Also, it seems you have div#area in your template as well. You should not include the 'el' itself in the template.

thanks @fbynite

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but your answer results in two `DOM` elements having the same `id` attribute.

Comment: Yea. Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice that OP has div#area in his template as well which, should be removed. http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/15/